# Не могу запустить эмулятор в Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, эмулятор

При нажатии на кнопку RUN выскакивает ошибка:

> This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled.

вот скрин экрана: https://prnt.sc/1094l31

В интернете нашел решение(или не решение), в файл gradle.properties поставил код:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Но сейчас выскакивает другая ошибка:

> error: cannot find symbol
> import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

вот скрин экрана: https://prnt.sc/1094oin

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: попробуйте удалить "/.idea/libraries" и провести синхронизацию градла снова

Comment: не помогает, ошибка также

Answer (score 0):

> попробуйте удалить "/.idea/libraries"

А затем File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Answer (score 0):

У вас проблема не с эмулятором студии, а видимо какой то бардак в подключенных библиотеках проекта - эмулятор тут совершено непричем. Ваш проект не может даже скомпилироваться в запускаемое приложение, не то что добраться до эмулятора.

Дело в том, что раньше гугл использовал библиотеки поддержки через пакет `android.support`, но с недавнего времени перешел на пакет `androidX`. В своем проекте вам надо привести все подключенные библиотеки поддержки к одному из вариантов (лучше новый androidX). Так же в коде использовать классы из соответствующих библиотек.

Например, класс `Fragment` теперь располагается в [androidx.fragment.app.Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment?hl=nb), а не `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` как ранее. Здесь мы видим, что в первом случае класс принадлежит новой библотеке поддержки androidX, а во втором старой `android.support`. Соответственно, какая библиотека поддержки подключена к проекту, классы той и необходимо импортировать в проект. Причем, совместить их не получится, надо выбрать что то одно.

В общем для решения конкретно этой ошибки, вам надо заменить импорт, выделенный серым:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

на следующее:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
```

Однако на скрине видно, что у вас еще много и других ошибок сборки проекта.

PS: Для обучения разработке рекомендую читать соответствующую литературу, например замечательную книгу ["Android. Программирование для профессионалов. 4-е издание"](https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?s=&showtopic=159318&view=findpost&p=102494211), где учтены все нюансы, последние нововведения и дается полное представление о андроид-разработке на примере создания реальных приложений практически по шагам

Answer (score 0):

Для работы эмулятора под АндроидХ в build.gradle должно быть (взял из своего проекта)

```
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
   implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-beta02'
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-beta01'
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
   implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
   implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.3'
   implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.3'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
}
```

попробуйте добавить у себя

```
androidx.v4.app.Fragment
```

источник https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/hello-world-androidx.html

Comment: Вы понимаете, что предлагаете имплементировать в чужой проект? Уверены, что в чужом проекте понадобятся именно эти библиотеки и не понадобятся никакие другие? Импорт фрагмента не правильный, в пакете androidX нет никакого пакета v4. Эмулятор не работает ни под каким androidX, это пакет поддержки гугл и нужен только на этапе сборки проекта, эмулятору, как и устройству, совершенно без разницы, какие библиотеки вы используете для сборки.

Comment: Я привел пример. Что бы человек понял, что к чему. Ни к чему я не призываю. И читайте какая ошибка у человека

Comment: Импорт из библиотеки androidX фрагмента: `import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`, а не то, что вы написали. Однако это вряд ли решит все проблемы, так как на скрине еще много ошибок далее.